# Spring boot jpa not catching exception when exception is thrown while executing procedure using entity manager

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, entitymanager

I have a procedure in SQL Server and I am executing that procedure using entity manager in spring boot application.

When an exception is thrown in that procedure, the method which it is executing that procedure is not catching the exception (I have included persistence exception in catch block).

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
@Configuration
public class SampleOperations {

@Autowired
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "SampleUnit")
@Qualifier("SampleEntityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager entityMgr;
public void method1(DModel mapObject) throws CustomException {
    boolean queryStatus = false;
    try {
        StoredProcedureQuery sp = entityMgr.createStoredProcedureQuery("proc_clean_current_version_tables");
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        sp.setParameter(1, mapObject.getCountry());
        sp.setParameter(2, mapObject.getVersion());
        sp.execute();
        entityMgr.close();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | PersistenceException e) {
        throw new Customxception(
                "Unable to execute procedure ");
    }
}
}
```

SQL server procedure

```
 BEGIN TRY
                    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #get_col_hdr;
                     CREATE TABLE #get_col_hdr(colName VARCHAR(MAX));
                     INSERT INTO #get_col_hdr
                     EXEC proc_get_column_header 
                          @tableId, 
                          @cntr;
                     SELECT @columnHeader = colName
                     FROM #get_col_hdr;
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  set @error_message = 'Unable to import tables from databases 
.'+ERROR_MESSAGE();
 THROW 60000, @error_message, 1;
 END CATCH
```

Comment: In my sqlserver procedure I have try and catch block around my code.

Comment: If you use try/catch in you SP then you won't be passing it back to your application? Best to post your SP code as well.